# Correct way to create a wrapper to connect UI and Data in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, angularjs-resource

I'm quite newbie with angularjs. And I'm trying to follow the best practises for this framework but I don't know how to get this working:

I've a factory that acts as interface for a remote RESTful API.

```
appServices.factory('UsersFactory', ['$resource', function($resource) {

    var baseUrl = "http://....";
    var actionUrl = baseUrl + "users/";

    return $resource(actionUrl + ":id", {id: "@id"},
    {
        'getAll': { 
            method: 'GET', 
            isArray:true
        },
        'assignRoleToUser':  { 
            'method': 'PUT',
            'url': actionUrl + ":id/assign-role-to-user",
            responseType: 'json'
        }
    });
}]);
```

This factory has the common function to get, create, update and delete users (get, put, post put) aswell as custom defined actions (assign role to user, for example).

Then I've a controller from a view where I show the users and I inject the factory to this controller.

And once the user press a button I can call something like:

```
UsersFactory.assignRoleToUser({id: 'userid', role: 'roleid'});
```

The problem comes when I want to extend this functionality for example with some confirmation dialog and some extra logic after assign the role to the user. 
Just some simple example:

```
// In controller....
$scope.asssignRoleToUser(id_user, id_role) {

  ModalFactory.showConfirmDialog(blablabla, function() {
      UsersFactory.assignRoleToUser({id: 'userid', role: 'roleid'}, function(){
          AlertsDialogs.showAlert("User assigned correctly");
      });
  });
}
```

To this point I now want to reuse the assignRoleToUser code in other views or directives. 
How can I achieve it? Creating a service that acts like an wrapper/interface of the UserFactory but adding the UI behaivour that could be reusable within my webapp?

Any help will be welcome :)

Comment: Are you going to reuse "AlertsDialog.showAlert..." code ? It looks pretty general already. If you have a lot of code here to notify users, you may create some common service for this and reuse it everywhere.

Comment: @PavelKutakov I had the idea to separate the Models in one service, the Alerts in another service and to use them into the "wrapper" that will encapsulate the user actions, so something like taking this "assignRoleToUser" function out from the controller and create a new service with it (Having injection of the ModalFactory, UsersFactory and AlertsDialogsService)

Comment: One more idea may be to use controller inheritance and implement all common stuff in the base controller.

Comment: @PavelKutakov this is what I thought at first, something like a main controller with the actions and inject it on each subcontroller. The only problem is that I don't know if this is the "angular way" or if instead of a maincontroller I should use a service or similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add UI behavior, then it is probably best to create a directive just for the UI behavior.

Like for example a confirmation dialog directive, that will then (after confirmation) call any function you pass to it.

But if you like, you can certainly create a service with your common UI functions and then inject it to any controller you need. As a standard though, you should manipulate the UI using directives.

Comment: I thought about using custom directives at first, but then I should be creating a lot of directives almost one for each action that requires a confirmation dialog or so right?
For me it looks more clear to have everything into a singleton instance taht will group every action for the user

Comment: No, you need just one confirmation dialog directive. You can pass it arguments to customize it for every situation. Like what function to call after confirm, specifics for appearance, etc.

Comment: I mean if I have to do several stuff like notifications, dialogs and so on, my business logic will be spread between all those directives instead of having one "logic" point of entry to call all actions for the users. And maybe this entry point will call (inside each action) the according directive